# Handle two While-loop's in a small Java-game

Tags: java, while-loop

I've been messing around with the CanvasPaint library, and I want to make a nice little game, where I can move a circle around, based on user-input.

My approach is to create 2 simultaneously running While-loops, the first looking for a new input from the user, and the second moving the circle.

Sorry, for my lack of experience posting this type of code, but i'm just started Java-coding.

Problem:
My "direction" variable is always 0, I cannot get any value to it :(

```
package canvas;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Scanner;

import TestPackage.CanvasPaint;

public class BilSpil extends Thread {

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

private int direction;

public void run() { //First array, checking user-input
    while(true) {
            System.out.print("Direction: ");
            direction = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

//Getter for user-input
public int getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    (new BilSpil()).start();

    BilSpil spilObject = new BilSpil(); //Create object of extended Thread.

    int commands = (spilObject.direction); //Raw command-data for circle


    //Game background
    int yBg = 10;

    CanvasPaint cp = new CanvasPaint(500,500);
    cp.setBackground(Color.black);

    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        cp.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        cp.paintLine(yBg, 500, yBg, 0); //Y-streger
        cp.paintLine(500, yBg, 0, yBg); //X-streger

        yBg += 10;
    }

    boolean gameIsLive = true;

    int x = 245;
    int y = 245;

    cp.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    cp.paintOval(x, y, 5, 5);

        while(gameIsLive) { //Second while-loop, moving the circle

            while(commands == 2) { //Down direction
                cp.paintOval(x, y+10, 5, 5);
                y += 10;
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                cp.repaintFrame();
            }
            while(commands == 4) { //Left direction
                cp.paintOval(x-10, y, 5, 5);
                x -= 10;
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                cp.repaintFrame();
            }
            while(commands == 8) { //UP direction
                cp.paintOval(x, y-10, 5, 5);
                y-= 10;
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                cp.repaintFrame();
            }
            while(commands == 6) { //RIGHT direction
                cp.paintOval(x+10, y, 5, 5);
                x += 10;
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                cp.repaintFrame();
            }
        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why direction is not changing is because you have two instances of `BilSpil` and are retrieving direction from the one that is not changing

```
 (new BilSpil()).start();

BilSpil spilObject = new BilSpil(); //Create object of extended Thread.

int commands = (spilObject.direction); //Raw command-data for circle
```

to get this part working you will have to do this:

```
    BilSpil spilObject = new BilSpil(); //Create object of extended Thread.
    spilObject.start();

    int commands = (spilObject.direction); //Raw command-data for circle
```

Your access to `direction` is not thread safe and I imagine it will cause some concurency exceptions to fire off.

instead I recommend implementing `java.util.concurrent.Callable` since you want to return something

```
/**
* The Callable<V> interface allows you to define a Object V that you will
* return. In this case we are returning the integer object wrapper Integer
*/
public class BilSpil implements Callable<Integer> {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
/**
*Since we defined our class to implement Callable<Integer> we have to override
* the abstract method V call() throws Exception, and in our case it is of 
*the type Integer
*/
@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception {
     /**
     *input.nextInt() will block and not return untill a integer is entered 
     * java autoboxes the int primitive to its wrapper class Integer automagically
     */
    return input.nextInt();
}
```

I would move everything into one loop and use a switch statement

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     //creates a executor service with a fixed number of threads
     //that this ExecutorService can access
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    //submitting a callable runs it asynchronously, executor returns
    //a Future object we can use later to get the returned value
    //once the callable is done executing.
    Future<Integer> userInput = executor.submit(new BilSpil());
    int commands = 0; 

    ...

    while (gameIsLive) { 
        if(userInput.isDone()){
            try {
                commands = userInput.get().intValue();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              commands = 0;
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
               commands = 0;
            }
            userInput = executor.submit(new BilSpil());
        }

        switch(commands){
            case 2:
                y += 10;
                break;
            case 4:
                x -= 10;
                break;
            case 8:
                y -= 10;
                break;
            case 6:
                x += 10;
                break;
        }
        cp.paintOval(x, y, 5, 5);
        cp.repaintFrame();
    }

}
```

another improvement you could do is get rid of the [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants)

```
public static final int MOVE_SPEED = 10;
public static final int DOWN = 2;
public static final int LEFT = 4;
public static final int UP = 8;
public static final int RIGHT = 6;
public static final int NO_INPUT = 0;
public static final long GAME_CLOCK = 1000L;
public static final int BODY_WIDTH = 5;
public static final int BODY_HEIGHT = 5;

... 

       while (gameIsLive) { 
        if(userInput.isDone()){
            try {
                commands = userInput.get().intValue();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              commands = NO_INPUT;
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
               commands = NO_INPUT;
            }
            userInput = executor.submit(new BilSpil());
        }

        switch(commands){
            case DOWN:
                y += MOVE_SPEED;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                x -= MOVE_SPEED;
                break;
            case UP:
                y -= MOVE_SPEED;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                x += MOVE_SPEED;
                break;
        }
        cp.paintOval(x, y, BODY_WIDTH, BODY_HEIGHT);
        cp.repaintFrame();
        try{Thread.sleep(GAME_CLOCK);}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Some reading material:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: Hi, Austin, and thanks for your code! I must say this looks amazing, you got the thing working, with a fraction of code :) Could I maybe ask you to very briefly to explain what happens here:
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
    return input.nextInt();
    }

And here?

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Future<Integer> userInput = executor.submit(new BilSpil());

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `while(true) { //do stuff };`, part of `//do stuff` has to include a `break;` to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do in the while block is getting the user input. There are multiple options and you should decide for one of them: keyboard, buttons, etc...

Once you know what the user wants to do, you should use a switch and no whiles (that's very incorrect as you won't go out of them):

```
while(gameIsLive) { //Second while-loop, moving the circle
    commands = getUserInput();
    switch (commands) {
    case 2: { //Down direction
            cp.paintOval(x, y+10, 5, 5);
            y += 10;
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            cp.repaintFrame();
        } break;
    case 4: { //Left direction
            cp.paintOval(x-10, y, 5, 5);
            x -= 10;
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            cp.repaintFrame();
        } break;
    case 8: { //UP direction
            cp.paintOval(x, y-10, 5, 5);
            y-= 10;
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            cp.repaintFrame();
        } break;
    case 6: { //RIGHT direction
            cp.paintOval(x+10, y, 5, 5);
            x += 10;
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            cp.repaintFrame();
        } break;
    }
```

If you tell us more about how you want to listen to user input and what are you using to display the game, maybe we can give you more guidelines.

Comment: I'm using the nextInt listening for keyboard input. I'm using a num-pad-order for controls e.g. 8 is Up, 2 is down, and so forth. If I use the switch-way, as you suggest, I'm not getting the continued movement. I want the circle to move around "Snake-game-a-like"